# Rcmdr Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk'

Tags: r, r-commander

I have no idea what I'm doing but I need to use R and Rcmdr for my statistics class. I am running OS X 10.7.5, using 3.1.2 for R.

I have downloaded R.

```
install.packages("Rcmdr")
```

Picked a mirror, downloaded all packages. I then typed in

```
library(Rcmdr)
```

And received this error:

```
Loading required package: splines
Loading required package: RcmdrMisc
Loading required package: car
Loading required package: sandwich
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
  call: system2("otool", c("-L", shQuote(DLL)), stdout = TRUE)
  error: error in running command
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Rcmdr’
sh: otool: command not found
```

When I do:

```
capabilities("tcltk")
# [1] TRUE
```

Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The R developers have tried to make a workaround for R not giving a useful error message when Tcl/Tk was not fully supported on a Mac. It seems R 3.1.2 depends on the otool from Xtools for this. However, you can download a patched version of R from http://r.research.att.com/ to remove the error.